# Fast way to find the mean of a function?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm writing code to evaluate the mean of functions it is passed, but where the functional form is not known beforehand. I have code below that does work, using scipy.integrate.quad, but it is rather slow. I was wondering does anybody know of a faster way?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.stats import norm

fn=norm(1,2).pdf  #A Gaussian as an example (mean 1 and standard deviation 2)

mean=quad(lambda x: x*fn(x), -100, 100)[0]  #Gives 0.9999... , which is good enough
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my computer your computations take only 0.12 seconds:

```
In [59]: %prun quad(lambda x: x*fn(x), -100,100)

         26740 function calls in 0.114 seconds
```

And I get the same result:

```
In [59]: quad(lambda x: x*fn(x), -100,100)
Out[59]: (0.9999999999999999, 5.793858187044747e-12)
```

Most of it is due to the fact that `fn` is a bounded method in scipy and python has to resolve a little bit until it finds the funtion to evaluate. You should try to pass a function instead.

In your example, if you let (I imported `scipy as sp`):

```
In [60]: fn2 = sp.stats._continuous_distns._norm_pdf
```

Then fn2 is a function (it is a standarized normal), so you have to tidy it a little bit to call it:

```
In [61]: quad(lambda x: x*fn2((x-a)/b)/b, -100,100)
Out[61]: (1.0, 4.712371011323367e-10)
```

Here `a` is the mean and `b` the standard deviation.

And it is 20 times faster:

```
In [62]: %prun quad(lambda x: x*fn2((x-a)/b)/b, -100,100)
         805 function calls in 0.006 seconds
```

Of course this example is a solution to your example, but the point I am triying to make is that you should pass functions to `quad` intead of methods in order to get it run faster.

Beware that, in what I did, I called "private" functions from scipy (they are not exactly private, but the pre-underscore means that it is intended to be internal to the module).